# proxy_pass a symfony application with nginx

Tags: symfony, nginx

I have a symfony application which offers a REST API. On another host (actually docker container) I have a frontend javascript application which is supposed to consume that API. I want to serve them from the same domain and host:

- / - should serve the frontend app
- /api/ - should serve the API

I configured nginx like so:

```
server {
    location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://apihost:8080/$1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    location / {
        root /var/www/;
    }
}
```

That works as long as I don't use the debug toolbar and there is no exception. In that case, the URLs (images, css, js) in the page don't contain the */api/* prefix causing 404s.

How can I configure either symfony or nginx to prepend that prefix to the urls?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: I was working on this and I think I finally managed to get it work...If I've got final answer I will post it

Comment: Did it work? Did you find an solution?